# list vs. incremental values security

Tags: security, f#

Can someone tell me the formal reason why list/arrays and such are considered more secure when it comes to incremental steps i.e (List.fold > loops).

Exampel code in F#

Functional way (list)

```
let rec sum lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> 0
    | x::xs -> x + sum xs
```

Imperative way (incremental)

```
let sum n m =
    let mutable s = 0
    for i=n to m do
        s <- s + i
    s
```

Comment: What do you mean by "more secure"?

Comment: harder to hack.

Comment: I don't know who would say that a list or an array is something that can be hacked. If you're in the .NET world, then lists will have about the same safety guarantees as arrays. They're both managed data structures.

Answer (score 0):

If by security you mean "safer" -- then I think this will explain it some. To begin with if you're summing a list, a `fold` should be somewhat safer as it removes the need for the programmer to correctly index the list:

```
let sum lst =
    let mutable s = 0
    for i=0 to (List.length lst - 1) do 
        s <- s + lst.[i]
    s
```

You avoid a lot of pitfalls completely by using the library function:

```
let sum lst = 
    let folder acc element = 
        acc + element
    List.fold folder 0 lst
```

The fold handles all the edge cases for you, in terms of indices, and list length. (note: this could also be done with a `List.reduce (+) lst` however that does *not* handle an empty list, where as a fold does).

The short of it all is that it keeps the programmer from making mistakes on silly index math, and keeps the focus on the actual logic of what is being done.

EDIT: I ironically messed up the index logic in my initial post

Comment: My example was simple.. I know that there is a lot of higher order function to get around such stuff.. but thanks

Comment: Yes, my answer assumed "safety" rather than "security", poor assumption on my part, sorry about that.